# Exception EStackOverflow in module rtl270.bpl at 0012F044. Stack overflow

Tags: delphi, installation, pascal

[image: error in image]

Any idea why? I tried reinstalling it into different drives, but still no luck.

Comment: Clearly a bug in the IDE/Installer. Nothing we can do about it here. [File a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.

Comment: It might also be a failing installed package? All installed packages as BPL's also link to rtl270.BPL.   I don't use many packages so don't know by heart to force Delphi to start without loading packages (so you can enter the packages install  dialog).  Try renaming the bpls for the most recently installed package and try to start again, Delphi will complain, but ignore that.

Comment: Edit the shortcut that starts Delphi and add `-rFoo` to the end, and then launch Delphi. This starts it using a new, empty registry section named *Foo*, which will load only the standard out-of-the-box components, without any third party components/wizards/experts. Does the problem still happen? If so, it's a bug in the IDE. If not, it's an issue with additional packages/wizards/experts you've installed, and you can reinstall them one at a time, restarting the IDE after each one has been installed, to see if the problem happens again. If it does, the last package you installed is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had that same problem, for me was the windows defender blocking the bds.exe. Take a look at the protection history and see if it is being blocked there